# IBM MQ JmqiException:JMSWMQ0019 and JMSCMQ0001

Tags: java, spring, ibm-mq

I am connecting to two IBM MQ servers from a same client.

When the service is started, everything is fine, but if it continues to run for 5-6 days, the CPU will rise, and the number of MQ connections will also be cut off.

Looking at the log, will find the following message. The relevant keywords have been searched, but the exact reason has not been found. Would anyone know where this problem is?

we also run many asynchronous spring @schedules by using @async

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you have long, idle connections they may grow stale. What network hardware is between your code and the host?

Comment: We have experienced that our connections were broken by the load balance machine(f5) but there's no load balance machine in this project.